# How to use vim-youcompleteme

Tags: vim-plugin

I downloaded `vim-youcompleteme` from the software center in Ubuntu. But I don't know how to make it work. When I restarted vim and tested, nothing special occurred. And `vim-syntastic` is the same. Could someone tell me how to make them work? Should I do something with my `~/.vimrc` ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the package-specific README (`/usr/share/doc/vim-youcompleteme/README.Debian`):

```
vim-youcompleteme
-----------------

A code completion plugin for Vim. This package designed to work with
vim-addon-manager. To use this addon install vim-addon-manager package first
and use this command:

  $ vam install youcompleteme
```

`vim-addon-manager` is recommended by when `vim-youcompleteme`, so there's a good chance it is already installed. If not:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-addon-manager
```

And then run the command given in the README. `vim-syntastic` is only available for 14.10, from the results in [the package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vim-syntastic), but given that it explicitly depends on `vim-addon-manager`, I'd say something similar applies to it as well.

Answer (score 8):

In 18.04 it's just;

```
sudo apt install vim-youcompleteme
vim-addon-manager install youcompleteme
```

The ubuntu version does not support Java so you may want the latest version depending on your language of choise, so alternativly;

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.py --all
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this :

Put this at the top of your .vimrc to use Vundle.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Run following to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose use to use [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), I think it is available on Ubuntu. It is like `vundle`, but the only thing to do is clone git repos on the others addons not listed on vam or available like a package on Ubuntu in the directory `.vim/bundle`.

Comment: The package `vim-pathogen` actually does exist in Ubuntu's repos, and may be installed using the command `sudo apt-get install -y vim-pathogen`.